# Ordered List with Unique users

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity

Trying to get a highscore list based on some input values. The database is old and integrated in different places so cannot change anything there.

I get an nice ordered list but it's **when I'm trying to make users unique it doesn't care about my order anymore.**

What I'm doing when requesting data is in the order of

1. Game Id (many different game types)
2. If dates (between these dates)
3. Order by score and created timestamp
4. Of what we got so far, now remove all duplicated rows based on email

   Get top 10

This is what I have.

```
// Get current game based on id
var query = db.GameResult.Where(w => w.GameId == gameId);

// Get playes after 
if(request.DateStart.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(w => w.CreatedTime >= request.DateStart);
}
// Get playes before
if (request.DateEnd.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(w => w.CreatedTime <= request.DateEnd);
}

// Score & created order by
if (request.SortScoreDesc && request.SortDateDesc)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).ThenByDescending(o => o.CreatedTime);
}
else if (!request.SortScoreDesc && !request.SortDateDesc)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(o => o.Score).ThenBy(o => o.CreatedTime);
}
else if (!request.SortScoreDesc && request.SortDateDesc)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(o => o.Score).ThenByDescending(o => o.CreatedTime);
}
else if (request.SortScoreDesc && !request.SortDateDesc)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).ThenBy(o => o.CreatedTime);
}

// Get unique users
if (request.Unique)
{
    // CANNOT GET TO WORK
    //query = query.GroupBy(o => o.Email).Select(r => r.FirstOrDefault());
}

query = query.Take(request.Rows);

List <GameResult> querylist = query.ToList();
```

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly

Comment: When running script without if (request.Unique) it works, everything is sorted correctly. But when I'm trying to make the list unique (by email) the list get scrambled.

Comment: if Unique is true you want to get unique users based on emailId ! but i feel one email will have only one linked user ,right? also, add the GameResult class to the question.

Comment: I assume that this is Linq-to-Entity which generates SQL against the database. In that case OrderBy will be ignored because ORDER BY within GROUP BY or DISTINCT is not allowed in SQL.

Comment: So for a top 10 list I need to grab 100 users and then loop my result with manual check to get the top 10 unique rows?

Comment: You should reorganize the query in a way that the sorting statement appears after the grouping, ideally at the end.